# Trivial and Nontrivial Solutions to IVPs and the Existence and Uniqueness Theorem

Tags: calculus

This is a question about first order equations.

Ex: $\frac{dx}{dt} = x^2$,  $x=t^3/3+C$

If the initial value is a critical point of the function (eg: $x_0=0$), the function would have a trivial and non trivial solution: the solution $x(t) = 0$ and $x^3/3=t$.

Would this not contradict the Existence and Uniqueness Theorem because $t^2$ and $t^3/3$ are both continuous but there are two solutions to the IVP $x_0=0$? What am I missing here?

Edit: Made critical point an equilibrium point.

Answer (score 1):

If $x'(t)=t^2$, then $x(t)=\frac{1}{3}t^3+C$.

The initial value problem

$x'(t)=t^2, x(0)=0$ has the unique solution $x(t)=\frac{1}{3}t^3.$

Answer (score 0):

$x(t) \equiv 0$ is not a solution to $\frac{dx}{dt} = 2t$.

Comment: My bad, created a half stable point. How about now that $x_0$ is a fixed point? I'm reading Nonlinear Dynamics and Chaos by Strogatz and on page 27 on example 2.5.1 he does this.

Comment: Strogatz considers _autonomous_ equations (those of the form $\dot{x} = f(x)$), and you have dependence on $t$ in the rhs.

Comment: Right. Is it not possible to make a function so that f(x) and f'(x) are continuous and $\frac{dx}{dy}=f(x)$ has a fixed point that is not a half-stable point? Basically I'm trying to ask if the solution to the $x_0$ being a stable point always has the solution $x(t)=0$ like he has in the book.

Comment: Take $\frac{dx}{dt} = x^2$.  The zero equilibrium is half-stable: stable (even asymptotically) from the left, and unstable from the right.